# Allow smaller time intervals for email notifications about unread inbox messages

Tags: feature-request, answers, comments, notifications, email

Currently the shortest available interval for email notifications about unread inbox messages is 3 hours.

[image]

It would be great if also options for considerably shorter intervals would be available.

Background: some users might prefer to be notified earlier so they can quicker reply to answers or comments they receive. If one only gets the notification after 3 hours, some conversations will take unnecessarily long as other users in the conversation might already be off-line again.

Many other platform also provide the option of (near) real-time notifications, for example github just to name one.

Optionally a similar approach to Github's handling of issues/pull-request mail notification can be taken. Each question has one email thread and all the answers/comments will be in that thread indicating in their header whether it is answer or comment. This approach wouldn't clutter user's inbox. The email would appear as soon as answers/comments are posted.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot keep your connection to the site and leave a tab open?

Comment: Nice question! The minimum value of 3 hours is even more strange considering that one can configure mails about new questions every 15 min. In case you use mac, this app might be helpful: https://github.com/ghewgill/senotifier

Comment: @Scratte, keeping the tab open isn't enough. You have to keep the window always on focus too or keep checking it from time to time which is a bad user experience.

Comment: Arguably better than being bombarded with emails.

Comment: @Zoe The email notifications can be adjusted in the profile and AFAIK they are off by default. No bombardment unless you want it

Comment: @Zoe If you worry your inbox could be flooded with emails from comments and answers and would clutter your inbox then a similar approach to Github issues/pull request mail notification can be taken.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see much value in that request. If one is not willing to spend first 15 minutes after posting the question in the browser waiting for comments than it really does not matter how long subsequent interaction will take. Most subsequent interactions are generally from people randomly found the post or see if from one of review queues and those people are not necessary interested/free for dialog about particular question.

3 hours for summary of updates seem to be short enough - all other communications outside initial 10-20 minutes will be really asynchronous with multiple hours of delay.

Comment: Waiting for 15 minutes after posting isn't going to make the questions answered faster, hence most people don't do that and they proceed with their work. And yes, initial interaction from users is random, but implementing this could make subsequent interaction with those users faster.

Answer (score -6):

This feature actually exists.

If you don't check your global inbox after 24 hours, you'll get an email message from Stack Overflow showing you what you missed.

As comments and answers are things that land in your global inbox, you'll get an email message from those if you don't log in/check your inbox for a day.

24 hours seems like a reasonable amount of time to give people the opportunity to respond.  There are a lot of slow tags out there which don't get the same foot traffic, and not everyone is lurking on Stack Overflow every waking moment (and neither should they be).

Comment: The question is how to decrease this time interval. In the profile it can only be decreased to 3 hours.